# Can I use the router to load models and views in backbone.js?

Tags: model-view-controller, backbone.js, router

Can I use the Router to navigate through views and load models based on the routes? If possible can someone write a router code for this scenario?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Routers should set up the current state of your Backbone application, i.e. they should set up the views and models.

I've written you a [crude example](http://jsfiddle.net/joshleitzel/7cBh6/), but you can get the gist. As with most things in Backbone, there's more than one way to do it. I personally would not take the approach I demonstrated, because it requires the views to know of the router's existence. What would be more appropriate is to create an event-driven model, in which the views trigger events and the router listens to them. When the router picks up a new event from a view, it can `navigate` appropriately, and the navigation function can call the appropriate view mechanisms.